# Hide popup windows in pyshark.filecapture

Tags: python, pyshark

I am getting 2 tshark.exe popup windows while executing `FileCapture`code below. Can someone let me know how to hide those windows?

```
import pyshark
import binascii
import struct

cap = pyshark.FileCapture(r"C:\Users\step16.pcapng", display_filter= r"data contains f1:f3:f1:f2")
j=0
for i in cap:
      caplen = cap[j].data.len
      modvalue = "caplen % 2"
      if (modvalue != 0):
          reqlen = caplen

      j =  j + 1
```

Comment: When is this code being called?

Maybe it is being called twice.

Comment: I would suggest that you should include perhaps a minimal code that reproduces your problem so that a community member is easily able to test the code to suggest an answer.

Comment: @mbbce, I have added minimal code.